# XMLHttpRequest in NodeWebkit, status = 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, node-webkit

This works in Chrome when doing it on my local server. However, when I transfer over to NodeWebkit, it fails with status === 0.

```
function ReadText(filename) {
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", filename, true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (txtFile.readyState === 4) // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
        {
            if (txtFile.status === 200) // Makes sure it's found the file.
            {
                g_FileLoadContents = txtFile.responseText;
                ReadFile();
            }
        }
    }
    txtFile.send(null);
};
```

g_FileLoadContents is a global and ReadFile is a function that does some work on g_FileLoadContents... but it does not get that far in the NodeWebkit (Again, I'll stress all is ok in Chrome when on my local server).

In NodeWebkit I watch txtFile.readyState change up to 4, but then txtFile.status is 0.

Why is the status 0? When I use the nodeWebkit, should I just let the status be 0 in my code above?

I hope someone can explain, as I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP status codes are returned by webservers. Presumedly your local server returns 200 when you're doing this in Chrome, but node-webkit just returns 0 ([Unknown?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)).

Normally reading local files is restricted though. Does the code above actually produce the file contents? Even so, if you're trying to read files in node-webkit I would suggest using the [node fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to access the filesystem directly.

Comment: Yes it did produce the file contents, but I think you are right, I should use the fs module. Is there any way you can detect, in-code, whether you are using the node-webkit or if it is on a normal web-page? Then I could double-code the solution.

Comment: Found the WebNodekit check, courtesy GrandMasterB. var isNodeWebkit = (typeof process == "object"); Then you can do WebNodeKit specific code. if (isNodeWebkit) { console.log( 'in node-webkit v' + process.versions['node-webkit']);}

Comment: Yeah, although I prefer to bail instead if my app happens to be run in a browser, e.g. (untested) `if (typeof process === 'undefined') { $('body').html('This application does not run in a web browser.'); }` and exit immediately.